# Making FreeBSD as a local development server

Tags: linux, unix, networking, virtualbox, freebsd

I have installed FreeBSD 9.1 release by the help of Virtual Box running on Windows 7.
On FreeBSD, I have installed PHP and Apache using ports.

Now I wish to do all my development from the Windows operating system, transfer the written code via FTP and see the result of my development activity on my Windows browser.

For achieving this I would need to make this FreeBSD installation as a server which can serve the content to my browser on Windows 7.

I have tried to done several changes to `/etc/rc.conf` but none of them allow me to access the FreeBSD from Windows.

I had tried making the following entries in the `/etc/rc.conf`

```
hostname="fbsd.web.in"
ifconfig_em0="inet 192.168.1.222 netmask 255.255.255.0"
```

"em0" is my network interface which I have check by running the command `ifconfig`
I have been trying to achieve this for the last 2 days by trying out different configurations but nothing has helped so far.

Just for information I have a wifi network at my place.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Move question to serverfault.

Comment: putting the same question again might not be a good idea. Since there is "networking" tag available in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice tutorial on how to set it up: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/development/

Just remember to enable bridged networking in your VM settings.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I just added the "Port Forwarding" option and I was able to access the webpages on Windows that were delivered by FreeBSD.

Comment: But I would also like to send my files over to the FreeBSD via FTP. That is not achieved right now. I would also want to access my freeBSD  terminal via Putty so that I can copy-paste some of the commands. :P

Can you help ?